# PHP prepared insert using procederal style

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to switch my signup page to use mysqli_stmt_prepare procederal style.

It works perfectly without preparing so I'm pretty sure the database and everything else is hooked up correctly.

I've followed the PHP manual on how to do this but I keep on getting a blank white page back from PHP.

Here's my code, if anybody can spot what I'm doing wrong I'd be extremly grateful.

Also am not sure if I should put mysqli_real_escape in the front or not.

```
    $postuser = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $postpass = sha1($_POST['userpass']);
    $postemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['useremail']);

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'INSERT INTO users (username, userpass, useremail, userdate)
    VALUES(     '" . ? . "', 
                '" . ? . "', 
                '" . ? . "',
                NOW())')) 
    {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $postuser, $postpass, $postemail);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 

    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    } 



    if(!$stmt)  
    {  
        //something went wrong, display the error  
        echo '<ul class="ulstylecenter">
            <li>Something went wrong while signing in. Please try again later.</li>
            <li>If you are not redirected in 5 seconds please <a href="/home.php">click here</a>.</li>
            </ul>'; 
            header('Refresh: 5;url=/home.php');
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to sanitize input when using prepared statements as the statement and the values are sent separately. You should however sanitize data when being displayed from the db.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done PHP, but i'm quite sure it isn't possible to echo something THEN modify the headers, so your "else" won't work. For debugging purpose, you might prefer using standard error messages. when going live, your approach is OK except you might want to log the error (so that you know there was a problem) and do the redirection using meta-redirect or javascript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using prepared statements, you do must *not* escape the values, and you must *not* put the `?` placeholder in quotes in the SQL.

```
$postuser = $_POST['username'];
$postpass = sha1($_POST['userpass']);
$postemail = $_POST['useremail'];

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'INSERT INTO users (username, userpass, useremail, userdate)
VALUES(?, ? ?, NOW()'))
```

This is the same whether you use the procedural or OO style -- the only difference between the two is the syntax for calling the functions.

Comment: Worked perfectly Thanks, My only question now is, Is mysqli_real_escape needed anywhere for extra security or is the prepared statement enough security in itself?

Comment: Not only is it not needed, it would be _wrong_. Think of prepared statements as escaping all the parameters. If you call `mysqli_real_escape_string` you'll be escaping them twice.

Comment: That's why I wrote `must not` rather than `should not` in my answer.